# How to add a secondary vertical axis to a timeline chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a timeseries chat plotting two different series, see here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGoHPodslxw01PVf8Yp4SI15saedY8iID3FegJg6lmg/

I would like to have 2 different Y-axes, one for value A and another for value B, so correlation (or lack of thereof) can be seen more easily. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a timeline chart that does not support multiple Y axes.

You can put the two series on different axes like this:

1. Choose **Setup > Chart type > Line chart**.
2. Choose **Customize > Series > value B > Axis > Right axis**.